# "An Internal Error Ocurred during SVN commit: length 16416 out of range, must be between 0 and 1384"

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse

I have a problem committing a bunch of .jar files with eclipse.
Maybe eclipse thinks they are text files and not binaries?

If that's the problem, how do I check that? And how do I change it?

If it is not, then what is it?

[image]

Comment: Funny. A Google search for the error message results in this Q as top item...

Comment: So nobody can tell me "look it up in Google"

Comment: Not too sure about the downvote *and* the accept mark. You can post (and accept after 2 days) a better explanation of your own if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of:

- eclipse
- jdk
- svn plugin

are you using?

could you copy the callstack you can see in the eclipse logs (in the "error view" of eclipse)

[This thread](http://www.nabble.com/Received-%22SVN:-Internal-Error%22-when-Committing-Executable-into-Subversion--td23639555.html), for instance, suggests that the OP was using th wrong JDK. Using the latest JDK (see [this eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)) here could be a good idea. (Same in [this other thread](http://www.fachschaft.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=198&t=13959)).
In both thread, a similar callstack shown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: length 16416 out of range; must be between 0 and 16384
   at gnu.javax.net.ssl.provider.Record.setLength(libgcj.so.81)
   at gnu.javax.net.ssl.provider.OutputSecurityParameters.encrypt(libgcj.so.81)
   at gnu.javax.net.ssl.provider.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(libgcj.so.81)
   at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(libgcj.so.81)
   at gnu.javax.net.ssl.provider.SSLSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream.write(libgcj.so.81)
   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(libgcj.so.81)
   at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNLogOutputStream.write(SVNLogOutputStream.java:65)
```